# How to add a where clause only if a certain variable is true?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select and add a where clause only if a certain variable is true. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENTS 
WHERE STUDENT_NAME IN ('John', 'Jane');
```

And my variable is `$P{isJohnOrJane}` which can be 0 or 1;

I've tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENTS 
WHERE $P{isJohnOrJane} = 1 
  AND STUDENT_NAME IN ('John', 'Jane')
```

and that works. But when `${isJohnOrJane} = 0` it does not select anything when it should select all the students.

Comment: `(STUDENT_NAME IN ('John', 'Jane') or ${isJohnOrJane}=0)`

Comment: you need to write an OR condition to select all students when `$P{isJohnOrJane}` is `0`. Without an `OR` condition, the query will only select students with names 'John' or 'Jane' when `$P{isJohnOrJane}` is `1`.

Comment: `$P{isJohnOrJane}` isn't a (T-SQL) variable; are you *injecting* into your statement rather than parametrising?

Comment: I sincerely hope you are not injecting. Note that using an `OR` can be very inefficient, it may be worth having separate queries and conditionally execute one of them from the clientside

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use proper SQL declared variables.  There are 2 ways to do this: use the variable directly in the query; or use it to determine the query to execute.

First example using the variable directly in the SQL query:

```
DECLARE @isJohnOrJane bit = 1;

SELECT * 
FROM STUDENTS 
WHERE ( @isJohnOrJane = 1 AND STUDENT_NAME IN ('John', 'Jane') )
     OR @isJohnOrJane = 0
```

Alternatively you can use IF logic to determine the execution:

```
IF @isJohnOrJane = 1
 BEGIN SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENT_NAME IN ('John', 'Jane') ) END
ELSE
 BEGIN SELECT * FROM STUDENTS END
```

Both will produce the same answer but IF logic works better to avoid weird looking queries containing variables, it uses indexes on table columns as intended, it is probably easier for others to understand, and can apply to multiple outcomes instead of just 2 like in your example.